# Error calling function with multiple arguments located in another python file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

On button press, trying to call a function with three arguments, the program breaks, however calling a function with no arguments executes correctly.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from another import Another
class MainWindow(Screen, Another):
    """ This class imports class Another from another.py file"""
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen, Another):
    """ This class imports class Another from another.py file"""
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    """ This class is to control screen operations."""
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

## another.py

```
class Another:

    def dummy_one(self):
        print("This is Alpha. This function has zero arguments")

    def dummy_two(self,one, two, three):
        """Just a test function"""
        print('This is:',one)
        print('This is:',two)
        print('This is:',three)
        print('This function has three positional arguments')

obj = Another()
obj.dummy_two('Beta','Gamma','Delta')
```

## my.kv

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Welcome to the MAIN SCREEN"
        Button:
            text: "Press Me, See the console output!!!"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
            on_press:
                root.dummy_one() # This executes fine, has zero arguments


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Welcome to the SECOND SCREEN"
        Button:
            text: "Press Me, See the console output. Go back home!!!"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            on_press:
                root.dummy_two()  # This throws error, has three positional arguments
```

Error on button press in the second screen: 
TypeError: dummy_two() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'one', 'two', and 'three'

The function dummy_two(self,one, two, three), executes correctly when file another.py is run, but crashes when called from the main file (main.py).

Comment: I am confused, `root.dummy_two()` has 0 positional arguments (you pass nothing), did you mix which one errored and what one didn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `None` to the parameters as default values. Default values indicate that the function parameter will take that value, `None` if no argument value is passed during function call.

## Snippets

```
def dummy_two(self,one=None, two=None, three=None):
```